# python: random sampling from self-defined probability function

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

I have a piecewise quartic distribution with a probability density function:

```
p(x)= c(x/a)^2 if 0≤x<a; 
      c((b+a-x)^2/b)^2 if a≤x≤b;
      0 otherwise
```

Suppose c, a, b are known, I am trying to draw 100 random samples from the distribution. How can I do it with numpy/scipy?

Comment: Your function appears piecewise quartic rather than quadratic. Also -- is this intended to be the *density* function or the *cumulative distribution* function?

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks! have edited it. this is a density function.

Comment: One standard way is to find an explicit formula, `F^-1` for the inverse of the cumulative distribution function. That is doable here (although it will naturally be piecewise defined) and then use `F^-1(U)` where `U` is uniform on [0,1] to generate your samples. Note that `c` is easily computed from `a` and `b` by the requirement that the result integrates to 1.

Comment: @John Coleman your comment could be an answer, because, er, this is *the* answer

Comment: @ev-br I resisted the idea at first since the algebra seemed daunting and I didn't like the idea of posting a code-free answer, but then I found a way to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One standard way is to find an explicit formula, `G = F^-1` for the inverse of the cumulative distribution function. That is doable here (although it will naturally be piecewise defined) and then use `G(U)` where `U` is uniform on [0,1] to generate your samples.

In this case, I *think* that I worked out the details, but you will need to check the Calculus/Algebra.

First of all, to streamline things it helps to introduce a couple of new parameters. Let

```
f(a,b,c,d,x) = c*x**2 #if 0 <= x <= a
```

and

```
f(a,b,c,d,x) = d*(x-e)**4 #if a < x <= b
```

Then your `p(x)` is given by

```
p(x) = f(a,b,c/a**2,c/b**2,a+b)
```

I integrated `f` to find the cumulative distribution and then inverted and got the following:

```
def Finverse(a,b,c,d,e,x):
    if x <= (c*a**3)/3:
        return (3*x/c)**(1/3)
    else:
        return e + ((a-e)**5 - (5*c*a**3)/(3*d))**(1/5)
```

Assuming this is right, then simply:

```
def randX(a,b,c):
    u = random.random()
    return Finverse(a,b,c/a**2,c/b**2,a+b,u)
```

In this case it was possible to work out an explicit formula. When you can't work out such a formula for the inverse, consider using the Monte Carlo methods described by @lucianopaz

Answer (score 4):

As your function is bounded both in `x` and `p(x)`, I recommend that you use [Monte Carlo rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). The basic principle is that you draw two uniform random numbers, one representing a candidate `x` in the `x` space bounds `[0,b]` and another representing `y`. If `y` is lower or equal to the normalized `p(x)`, then the sampled `x` is returned, if not it continues to the next iteration

```
import numpy as np
def rejection_sampler(p,xbounds,pmax):
    while True:
        x = np.random.rand(1)*(xbounds[1]-xbounds[0])+xbounds[0]
        y = np.random.rand(1)*pmax
        if y<=p(x):
            return x
```

Here, `p` should be a callable to your **normalized** piecewise probability density, `xbounds` can be a list or tuple containing the lower and upper bounds, and `pmax` the maximum of the probability density in the x interval.