# Python: how to create a distance network with a given distribution?

Tags: python, networking, distribution, euclidean-distance

I have `N` agents to place in a grid `n x n` following the (truncated Levy) distribution

`px =  (r + r0)**(-beta)*exp(-r/k)`

Each agent has two favorite cells: `home` and `work` and `px` is the probability for each agent to move from  `home` and `work` with a distance `r`.

```
def returnLevy(r, beta):
    r0 = 100
    k = 1500
    px = (r + r0)**(-beta)*exp(-r/k)
    return px
```

I have compute the distance among all the cells in my grid, so

```
allDistances.head(5):

    distances   cell_a  cell_b  
0   1.322959      0       1 
1   0.717737      0       2 
2   0.454170      0       3 
3   0.321495      0       4 
4   0.454248      0       5
```

I would like to know if there is a way to randomly assign to each agent a distance `r` from `home` and `work` following the aforementioned distribution. At the end I would like to have a dataframe:

```
agentsCells 

    distance    home    work    
0   1.322959     320    1089    
1   0.717737      4      765    
2   0.454170     2100    388
```

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, you might as well upvote the answer, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own custom `pdf` using `scipy` and use this to calculate useful metrics of your probability density

```
import scipy.stats as st

class LevyPDF(st.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self,r):
        r0 = 100
        k = 1500
        return (r + r0)**(-beta)*exp(-r/k) #Normalized over its range [minValue,maxValue]

my_cv = LevyPDF(a=minValue, b=maxValue, name='LevyPDF')
```

To randomly draw values you have to calculate at first the cumulative distribution function (`cdf`) and then invert it to get the `icdf`. This can now be used the draw the random values following your `pdf` (you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470070/python-random-sampling-from-self-defined-probability-function)).
If you have calculated the `cdf`, you can check your result using the numerical result of `my_cv.cdf()`.

Comment: If I have `minValue = 0` and `maxValue = 48` `x = np.linspace(minValue, minValue, (minValue-minValue)*2)` and then `sum(my_cv.cdf(x))=2.134`. I thought that this value should be `1`.

Comment: You have to normalize your `pdf` by yourself. I think, that the equation you gave in your question is not normalized at all.