# scipy rv_continuous very slow

Tags: python, class, scipy, distribution

I am using a custom function `f(x)` to define a custom distribution using `copy`'s  `rv_continuous` class. My code is

```
class my_pdf_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, integral):
        return f(x)/integral
```

where `integral` ensure the normalisation. I am able to create an instance of it with

```
my_pdf = my_pdf_gen(my_int,a = a, b = b, name = 'my pdf')
```

with `a,b` the upper and lower limit of the value's range, and `my_int= scipy.integrate.quad(f, a, b)[0]`.
I am also able to create a random sample of data using `my_pdf.rvs(my_int, size = 5)`, but this is very slow. (Up to 6 seconds when `size=9`).

I read that one should also overwrite some other methods in the class (like `_ppf`), but from the examples I found it isn't clear to me how to achieve it in my case.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you recompute integral each time?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux since it may was a bit tricky to evaluate I stored it in a value and call it each time

Comment: ok, so next to reimplement would be _ppf, which is actually inverse CDF, sampling is basically `return ppf(randomU01);`. I would also advice to look at what you have and see that everything is vectorized (it could take a numpy vector of values and return vector of results). Otherwise you would see multiple calls of your functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing approach and using Monte Carlo's rejection sampler method

```
def rejection_sampler(p,xbounds,pmax):
    while True:
        x = np.random.rand(1)*(xbounds[1]-xbounds[0])+xbounds[0]
        y = np.random.rand(1)*pmax
        if y<=p(x):
            return x
```

where `p` is the probability density function, `xbounds` is a tuple containing the upper and lower limits of of the pdf and `pmax` is the maximum value of the pdf on the domain.

Monte Carlo's rejection sampler was suggested here: [python: random sampling from self-defined probability function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470070/python-random-sampling-from-self-defined-probability-function)

Answer (score 1):

It's expected to be slow since the generic implementation does root-solving for cdf, which itself uses numerical integration.

So your best bet is to provide a `_ppf` or `_rvs` implementation. How to do this greatly depends on the details of `f(x)`. If you cannot solve `f(x) = r` analytically, consider tabulating / inverse interpolation or rejection sampling.