# Gumbel half distribution

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics, probability-density

I have generated a probability density function in python using scipy using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gumbel_l
import numpy as np

data = gumbel_l.rvs(size=100000)
data = np.sort(data)

plt.hist(data, bins=50, density=True)
plt.plot(data, gumbel_l.pdf(data))
plt.show()
```

My quesiton is if there is a way to get a one tailed distribution of this, namely the left side of the distribution, both to generate it and to fit a pdf to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom [`rv_continuous` subclass](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous). The minimum requirement, is that the custom class provides a `pdf`.  The `pdf` can be obtained from `gumbel_l`'s `pdf` up till `x = 0` and being zero for positive `x`.  The `pdf` needs to be normalized to get its area equal to `1`, for which we can divide by `gumbel_l`'s `cdf(0)`.

With only the `pdf` implemented, you'll notice that obtaining random variates (`.rvs`) will be rather slow. [Scipy rv_continuous very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498793/scipy-rv-continuous-very-slow) explains this can be remedied by generating too many variates and throwing away the values that are too high, or by providing an implementation for the `ppf`.

As the `ppf` can be obtained straightforward from `gumbel_l`'s `ppf`, the code below implements that solution.  A similar approach can be used to truncate at another position, or even to truncate at two spots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gumbel_l, rv_continuous
import numpy as np

class gumbel_l_trunc_gen(rv_continuous):
    "truncated gumbel_l distribution"

    def __init__(self, name='gumbel_l_trunc'):
        self.gumbel_l_cdf_0 = gumbel_l.cdf(0)
        self.gumbel_trunc_normalize = 1 / self.gumbel_l_cdf_0
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def _pdf(self, x):
        return np.where(x <= 0, gumbel_l.pdf(x) * self.gumbel_trunc_normalize, 0)

    def _cdf(self, x):
        return np.where(x <= 0, gumbel_l.cdf(x) * self.gumbel_trunc_normalize, 1)

    def _ppf(self, x):
        return gumbel_l.ppf(x * self.gumbel_l_cdf_0)

gumbel_l_trunc = gumbel_l_trunc_gen()

data = gumbel_l_trunc.rvs(size=100000)

x = np.linspace(min(data), 1, 500)
plt.hist(data, bins=50, density=True)
plt.plot(x, gumbel_l_trunc.pdf(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: truncated gumbel_l with pdf]